# Where to ask questions related to both software and entrepreneurship?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As the title says, where should I ask questions (in the Stack Overflow group of sites) that fall both into software and entrepreneurship categories.

**Edit:**

I have ideas (related to software) that I want to convert to business options and for that I need to ask related question on a discussion platform.

**For example**: What are suggested next steps when I have new ideas on improving existing software products (third party) and on launching new ones and want to get suggestions on where to start from other people from the software/business community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only forum related to entrepreneurship is [On Startups](http://answers.onstartups.com/), so that narrows the selection. It has 250 questions [tagged software](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/software).

Outside the Stack Overflow group of sites there's also for example [The Business of Software](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz) forum.